# XSLT 2.0 Regex with Ampersands

Tags: regex, xslt

I'm trying to convert text files into valid HTML. I want to change the `&lt;&lt;` into an `<dfn>` element, and the `&gt;&gt;` into the closing `</dfn>` element.

Sample source document:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
           <p>The term &lt;&lt;absorb&gt;&gt;means foo. 
              The term &lt;&lt;evaporate&gt;&gt; 
              means to foo.</p>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Unsuccessful code so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output
        method="xhtml"
        html-version="5.0"
        omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        encoding="utf-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/text()">        
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(&lt;&lt;)(\.?)(&gt;&gt;)" flags="sx">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <dfn>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                </dfn>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Various versions of the regex caught the left side `&lt;&lt;`, but I could never match further than that. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `regex="(&lt;&lt;)(\.?)(&gt;&gt;)"` the `\.` matches a literal dot character while you want to match any character sequence preceding the `>>`, no? So you want `regex="(&lt;&lt;)(.*?)(&gt;&gt;)""` to capture the characters. See http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFi/1 for an example.

Comment: Thanks. Was an elementary mis-step for me. At least I was only one character off the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Just adapt your regex to target the string that you want to wrap in  tags:

```
<xsl:template match="*/text()">        
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;&lt;(.+?)&gt;&gt;" flags="sx">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <dfn>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
            </dfn>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>        
</xsl:template>
```